# A man marries and meets his two aunts, who have killed 12 men and buried them in the cellar

Tags: identify-this-movie

The plot is:

A man who has many objections against marriage, gets married, and after that goes to his aunts house. There they meet. But his aunts have killed 12 men and have buried them all in the cellar.

Then the brother appears with a doctor (a plastic surgeon). Brother's face is filled with stitches and he is a cold, stonehearted person.

In the house, there is another man, who thinks he is the president of the United States and once a while generates a loud sound with his military trumpet.

The overall plot seems to be both funny, and thrilling.

What is the name of this movie?

Comment: You have virtually 100% of the plot dramatized here, but lack the title? Was this a quiz?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Arsenic and Old Lace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arsenic_and_Old_Lace_%28film%29) (1944)

From Wikipedia:

> The play is a farcical black comedy revolving around Mortimer Brewster, a drama critic who must deal with his crazy, homicidal family and local police in Brooklyn, NY, as he debates whether to go through with his recent promise to marry the woman he loves. His family includes two spinster aunts who have taken to murdering lonely old men by poisoning them with a glass of home-made elderberry wine laced with arsenic, strychnine, and "just a pinch" of cyanide; a brother who believes he is Theodore Roosevelt and digs locks for the Panama Canal in the cellar of the Brewster home (which then serve as graves for the aunts' victims); and a murderous brother who has received plastic surgery performed by an alcoholic accomplice, Dr. Einstein (a character based on real-life gangland surgeon Joseph Moran) to conceal his identity and now looks like horror-film actor Boris Karloff (a self-referential joke, as the part was originally played by Karloff). The film adaptation follows the same basic plot, with a few minor changes.

Comment: dang! beat me to it!